# Word for commuter train compartment

Tags: word-request

I am writing an essay for my English class.

I would appreciate it if you could point out, what is the each of divided train in the subway in English?

I expressed it as 'train compartment' in my writing
and in Korea, each compartment is numbered on platform.

> Suppose that you are on your way to work or school in rush hour, and you have been waiting for a train at the platform randomly, there are trains coming in, doors open, and you finally see the people crowed in the car already thinking that you surely will not be able to get on this train
>
> So I would like to introduce an application designed for the poor people who wait for a train in the crowded specific locations simply because there is a stairway right a head when you get off at the destination.
>   This application shows the level of congestion for **each train compartment of incoming train**.

Comment: I'm sorry but we don't accept questions asking for proofreading or phrasing help here and we don't review text for fluency.

Comment: As @Catija says, we do not accept general proofreading requests. However, you did ask one question that is acceptable, and I've edited your question in a way that allows it to be reopened.

Comment: If you could provide a photograph or diagram of what you are looking for, we could be more certain. On a commuter train (that term is itself used differently in different parts of the world) I think noah's answer of *car* or *carriage* is likely to be right, but train cars or carriages can also have *[compartments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corridor_coach)* or *[berths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berth_(sleeping))* within them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English you'd generally say "car", while in British English you'd generally say "carriage".  One exception is in London where the term "car" is used.

See: https://ggwash.org/view/41911/metro-wants-you-to-know-when-an-8-car-train-is-coming from the Washington DC Metro